# uwsgi and nginx simple setup without virtual env

Tags: nginx, wsgi

are there any steps to setup uwsgi with nginx with a simple wsgi python script. Most of the places I see only django and flask and other frameworks are being setup. Also I need steps to serve static files.. are there any  .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are two steps: uwsgi configuration and nginx configuration.

The simplest uwsgi configuration is as follows (uwsgi accepts many different configuration formats, in this example I use xml):

```
<uwsgi>
    <chdir>/path/to/your/script/</chdir>
    <pythonpath>/path/to/your/script/</pythonpath>
    <processes>2</processes>
    <module>myscript.wsgi:WSGIHandler()</module>
    <master/>
    <socket>/var/run/uwsgi/my_script.sock</socket>
</uwsgi>
```

The only tricky option here is `module`, it should point to your WSGI handler class.

Also, make sure that `/var/run/uwsgi/my_script.sock` is readable and writeable for both uwsgi and nginx.

The corresponding nginx configuration would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my.hostname;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/my_script.sock;
    }
}
```

If you need to serve static files, the smiplest way would be to add following code to the `server` clause:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /path/to/static/root/;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript;
    expires +1M;
}
```

This example already includes gzip compression and support for browser cache.